# Opencv compare дает непонятный результат

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Что это могло бы значить? Сама ошибка не гуглится [image]

Comment: О какой ошибке речь?

Comment: А что вообще значит выражение в out[30]?

Comment: Результат вызова функции в `In [30]`. Тип возвращаемого объекта `UMat` и его `id`.

Comment: Дело в том, что она не выводит нужный результат
У меня g - массив содержащий интенсивность серого в каждой ячейки, clone1 - массив состоящий только из 127(усредненного значения между максимальным и минимальным значением g), clone2 массив из нулей, который потом должен стать маской, но он по факту никак не изменяется

Comment: Попробуйте так: `clone2 = cv2.compare(g, clone1, cv2.CMP_GE)` . В документации ([`cv::compare`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga303cfb72acf8cbb36d884650c09a3a97))  дается такой пример: `dst = cv.compare(src1, src2, cmpop[, dst])`, квадратные скобки обозначают необязательный параметр, т.е. результат сравнения можно просто записать в переменную.

Comment: Дайте вопросу более конкретный заголовок.

Comment: Забавно, я сделал так
_clone2 = cv2.compare(g, clone1, cv2.CMP_GE)_
Картинка теперь при выводе clone2 не черная, а белая

Comment: @steam-ilka, значит для всех точек изображения условие истинное